# Allowing 3rd-party cookies in major 2020 browsers

Tags: web-browser, cookies, cors, same-origin-policy, iframe

I'm trying to get 3rd party cookies to work on  major mid-year 2020 browsers <sup>[1]</sup>. It's as simple as pointing an iframe to an external URL to make a cookied request and probably get the response thereafter (and the external site explicitly allows this).

Is there a solution to this problem? For example, some other header/s which the external site would set other than multiple combinations of `Allow-Access-` headers which simply doesn't work?

---

[1]: including Chrome incognito and iPhone safari.

Comment: What is the problem? How does this relate to information security?